# Python prettyXML and prettyHTML functions

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml

After much searching around the web, I couldn't find a single module which did a decent prettyXML or prettyHTML. Because:

```
<node>
    <child>
        Text
    </child>
</node>
```

Is flat out ridiculous, and not a good use of space.

```
<node>
    <child>Text</child>
</node>
```

Is much cleaner.

That's what spurred this project. I also created a similar, but works completely different prettyHTML. These are designed to work with the build in module, miniDOM. I'm looking for a full critique (i.e. anything that needs to be).

*Helper for prettyHTML:*

```
def addLineBreaks(txt, max_char, level, indent, indentSubLines = False):
    # If the length is already shorter, or if there is no space to be found
    if(len(txt) <= max_char or txt.find(" ") < 0):
        # Just return it
        return txt
    # end if

    # Up the level if indentSubLines
    if(indentSubLines): ++level

    ## Remember the last breakpoint's position
    # Start it where the last \n is found (in case what is passed has already been broken up some)
    lastPos = txt.rfind("\n")
    # If there was no "\n" then zero
    if(lastPos < 0): lastPos = 0

    # Get how many breaks we need to make. (-1) because 3 lines has 2 line breaks.
    numBreaks = math.ceil((len(txt) - lastPos) / max_char) - 1

    # Get the first space
    pos = tempPos = txt.find(" ", lastPos + 1)

    # Place that many minus one line breaks
    for i in range(numBreaks):
        # Keep searching until we find the furthest position we can, which will be
        # at tempPos - lastPos, where lastPos is the last break point.
        while((tempPos - lastPos) < max_char):
            # Assign the last result
            pos = tempPos
            # Find the next result after that one
            tempPos = txt.find(" ", tempPos + 1)
        # end while

        # If no break was found, then up to the next spot, which may
        # break what is wanted, but also prevents an infinite loop.
        if(pos == lastPos): pos = tempPos

        # Add the line break
        txt = txt[0:pos + 1] + "\n" + (indent * level) + txt[pos + 1:]
        # Remember where the break was put (+1 so it's past the \n)
        lastPos = pos + 1
    # end for

    # Return the new string
    return txt
# end addLineBreaks
```

*PrettyHTML:*

```
def prettyHTML(xml, indent = "  ", level = 0, max_char = -1):
    # If given text, just return it
    if(xml.nodeType in (xml.TEXT_NODE, xml.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)):
        return xml.toxml()
    # end if

    # Elements who's children will be indented
    indtCldrn = ['datalist', 'details', 'dl',
                 'map', 'math', 'menu',
                 'ol',
                 'select', 'svg',
                 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'thead', 'tr',
                 'ul'
    ]

    # Elements which will be placed on their own line, with all content / children
    ownLine = ['!DOCTYPE',
               'button',
               'dd', 'dt',
               'figcaption',
               'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6',
               'label', 'legend', 'li',
               'menuitem', 'meter',
               'optgroup', 'option', 'output',
               'progress',
               'rect',
               'style', 'summary',
               'td', 'textarea', 'th', 'title'
    ]

    # Elements which are self closing / void / whatever you want to call them
    selfClosing = ['area', 'base', 'br', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr']

    # Elements who's start / end tags will sandwich the content
    spaceAfter = ['address', 'article', 'aside', 'audio',
                  'blockquote', 'body',
                  'canvas', 'code',
                  'div',
                  'fieldset', 'figure', 'footer', 'form',
                  'head', 'hader', 'html',
                  'iframe',
                  'main',
                  'nav', 'noscript',
                  'object',
                  'p', 'pre',
                  'ruby',
                  'samp', 'script', 'section',
                  'table', 'template',
                  'video'
    ]

    ## This is just here so all HTML elements are accounted for
    """inline = ['a', 'abbr',
              'b', 'bdi', 'bdo',
              'cite',
              'data',
              'del', 'dfn',
              'em',
              'i', 'ins',
              'kbd',
              'mark',
              'q',
              'rp', 'rt',
              's', 'small', 'span', 'strong', 'sub', 'sup',
              'time',
              'u',
              'var',
    ]"""

    # Holds the pretty text
    pretty = ""

    # HTML is case insensitive, so make all node's lowercase
    nodeName = xml.nodeName.lower()

    ## Make the opening tag
    # Indent the tag, and add the node name
    openTag = (indent * level) + "<" + nodeName
    # Add the attributes (With the attribute name as lowercase)
    # This is tried as a precautionary
    try:
        for item in xml.attributes.items():
            openTag += " " + item[0].lower() + '="' + item[1] + '"'
        # end for
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    # end try

    # If we have a node which is self-closing
    if(nodeName in selfClosing):
        # Add the closing />
        openTag += " />"

        # Ensure it's not too long
        if(max_char > 0):
            openTag = addLineBreaks(openTag, max_char, level, indent, True)
        # end if

        # If not a <wbr />, then we also need to add a \n
        if(nodeName != "wbr"): openTag += "\n"

        # And return it, no need to process further
        return openTag
    # else, it's not a self closing tag
    else:
        # Add the closing >
        openTag += ">"
    # end if




    # If we want to indent the children
    if(nodeName in indtCldrn):
        # Add the open tag with a line break (indentation is already included)
        pretty += (openTag + "\n")

        # Get the prettyHTML for all the children, placing them one level deeper
        for child in xml.childNodes:
            pretty += prettyHTML(child, indent, level + 1, max_char)
        # end for

        # Add the closing tag with indentation
        pretty += ((indent * level) + "</" + nodeName + ">\n")

    # else if we want to sandwich everything.
    elif(nodeName in spaceAfter):
        # We assume that there is already a line break before (indentation is already included)
        pretty += (openTag + "\n")

        # Holds the inner text
        temp = ""

        # Get the prettyHTML for all the children
        for child in xml.childNodes:
            temp += prettyHTML(child, indent, level, max_char)
        # end for

        # If we have a limit
        if(max_char > 0):
            # Break it up
            temp = addLineBreaks(temp, max_char, level, indent)
        # end if

        # Append temp to pretty
        pretty += temp

        # Add the closing tag
        # If the last character isn't a \n, make it one so there is a break before the closing tag
        if(pretty[-1] != "\n"): pretty += "\n"

        # Add the closing tag with indentation
        pretty += ((indent * level) + "</" + nodeName + ">\n")

    # Else, we either have an inline, or a tag which should sit on its own line
    else:
        # We assume that there is already a line break before (indentation included)
        pretty += openTag

        # Add all children
        for child in xml.childNodes:
            pretty += child.toxml()
        # end for

        # Add the closing tag
        pretty += ("</" + nodeName + ">")

        # Then be sure to cut it up, if we have a max_char
        if(max_char > 0):
            # Break it up (If necessary)
            pretty = addLineBreaks(pretty, max_char, level, indent, True)
        # end if

        # If we have a tag which is supposed to be on its own line, add a line break
        if(nodeName in ownLine):
            pretty += "\n"
        # end if
    # end if

    # Return the now prettified text
    return pretty
# end prettyHTML
```

*Pretty XML:*

```
def prettyXML(xml, indent = "  ", level = 0):
    # Flag for whether or not to indent, or just wrap it
    hasNonText = False

    # For each node in the childNodes
    for node in xml.childNodes:
        # Check if there is something that isn't text
        if(node.nodeType not in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)):
            # If so, set the flag, and kill the loop
            hasNonText = True
            break
        # end if
    # end for

    # Store the pretty XML
    pretty = ""

    # If we have nonText
    if(hasNonText):
        # Add the indentation and start tag
        pretty += ((indent * level) + "<" + xml.nodeName)

        # Add the attributes (This is tried as a precaution)
        try:
            for item in xml.attributes.items():
                pretty += " " + item[0] + '="' + item[1] + '"'
            # end for
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        # end try

        # add the closing > and a line break
        pretty += ">\n"

        # Loop through each child
        for child in xml.childNodes:
            # And add it to pretty, moving it one level deeper
            pretty += prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1)
        # end for

        # Add the closing tag with indentation
        pretty += ((indent * level) + "</" + xml.nodeName + ">\n")

    # Else if it had no children
    elif(not xml.childNodes):
        # Just add the raw XML with indentation. Probably a self-closing tag
        pretty += ((indent * level) + xml.toxml() + "\n")

    # Else, it only had text children
    else:
        # Add the indentation and start tag
        pretty += ((indent * level) + "<" + xml.nodeName)

        # Add the attributes (like above)
        try:
            for item in xml.attributes.items():
                pretty += " " + item[0] + '="' + item[1] + '"'
            # end for
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        # end try

        # Add the closing >
        pretty += ">"

        # Add all children (which will just be text)
        for node in xml.childNodes:
            pretty += node.toxml()
        # end for

        # Add the closing tag
        pretty += "</" + xml.nodeName + ">\n"
    # end if

    return pretty
# end prettyXML
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this. To speed things up, do you have a quick demo on how to call these functions and what the arguments should do? It's hard to know what's a bug without any kind of specification.

Comment: @Veedrac, works fine for me: http://imgur.com/cvB3sWM Also, I'll put together an example.

Comment: Ah, I didn't expect you to want the trailing four `asdf`s not wrapped. I think I get it; the `max_char` is actually a misnamed `min_char`.

Comment: No, you were right. It wasn't working. Sorry, my day was about to end when I posted that. I'll update my code with other updates, again, once I fully analyze your answer.

Comment: Please note that you shouldn't edit the code in the question; [see here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/40768). You can post a *new* question (best leave a bit more room for this question) or post a link to updated code in the comments. See the link for justification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have in total three functions over 300 lines, so ~100 lines to a function. This is 5-10x too few functions for this amount of code.

A lot of your formatting looks like you've used a C-like language and can't handle writing Python. Stuff like

```
if(x):
    ...
# end if
```

which should just be

```
if x:
    ...
```

You even have

```
++level
```

which *actually* just means

```
+ ( + level )
```

Namely, this is a no-op.

My first criticism before I look at this more in-depth is to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and *stick* to it. As the code is written, it would alienate any current Python user.

---

I'm looking at `prettyXML` since it's the simpler of the two. You start with `has_non_text`, which is a great candidate for a function:

```
def has_non_text(xml):
    ret = False

    # For each node in the childNodes
    for node in xml.childNodes:
        # Check if there is something that isn't text
        if node.nodeType not in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
            # If so, set the flag, and kill the loop
            ret = True
            break

    return ret
```

Some of these comments are trivial, so remove them. Also, use an early return, since it's now a stand-alone function.

```
def has_non_text(xml):
    for node in xml.childNodes:
        # If not text
        if node.nodeType not in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
            return True

    return False
```

This would be even simpler with an `is_text` function:

```
def is_text(node):
    return node.nodeType in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)

def has_non_text(xml):
    return not all(is_text(node) for node in xml.childNodes)
```

Your comment

```
# Flag for whether or not to indent, or just wrap it
```

would be much better if it explained which action corresponded to which flag state. Something like

```
# Indent iff has non-text
```

`prettyXML` now looks like:

```
def prettyXML(xml, indent="  ", level=0):
    # Store the pretty XML
    pretty = ""

    # Indent iff has non-text
    if has_non_text(xml):
        ...

    # Else if it had no children
    elif not xml.childNodes:
        ...

    # Else, it only had text children
    else:
        ...

    return pretty
```

This would be better as

```
def prettyXML(xml, indent="  ", level=0):
    # Indent iff has non-text
    if has_non_text(xml):
        pretty = ""
        ...
        return pretty

    elif not xml.childNodes:
        pretty = ""
        ...
        return pretty

    # Only had text children
    else:
        pretty = ""
        ...
        return pretty
```

since each subsection is a logically separate action. In fact, you could make each a separate function if you wanted.

Consdier the first branch.

```
pretty = ""

# Add the indentation and start tag
pretty += (indent * level) + "<" + xml.nodeName

# Add the attributes (This is tried as a precaution)
try:
    for item in xml.attributes.items():
        pretty += " " + item[0] + '="' + item[1] + '"'
except AttributeError:
    pass

# add the closing > and a line break
pretty += ">\n"

# Loop through each child
for child in xml.childNodes:
    # And add it to pretty, moving it one level deeper
    pretty += prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1)

# Add the closing tag with indentation
pretty += ((indent * level) + "</" + xml.nodeName + ">\n")

return pretty
```

You should never do `+=` on strings in a loop unless you know enough to know it doesn't apply. In this case it definitely doesn't.

Here's an alternative:

```
pretty += "".join(" " + item[0] + '="' + item[1] + '"' for item in xml.attributes.items())
```

You should also use formatting, unpacking and move the loop out of the `try`:

```
try:
    attributes = xml.attributes.items()
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:    
    pretty += "".join(' {}="{}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)
```

The `"{}"` can be better replaced with `{!r}`, which uses the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the string. This is a better match although it's not entirely safe. Further, the `try` can be replaced with an `or`:

```
attributes = (xml.attributes or {}).items()
pretty += "".join(' {}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)
```

and change the outer parts.

You can then do the same for the child nodes:

```
pretty += "".join(prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1) for child in xml.childNodes)
```

and then put it together with a formatting string:

```
attributes = (xml.attributes or {}).items()
node_attrs = "".join(' {}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)
children   = "".join(prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1) for child in xml.childNodes)

make_node = (
    "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>\n"
    "{children}"
    "{tab}</{xml.nodeName}>\n"
).format

return make_node(node_attrs=node_attrs, children=children, tab=indent * level, xml=xml)
```

The second option is

```
elif not xml.childNodes:
    # Just add the raw XML with indentation. Probably a self-closing tag
    pretty = ""
    pretty += ((indent * level) + xml.toxml() + "\n")
    return pretty
```

Obviously this can become just

```
elif not xml.childNodes:
    # Just add the raw XML with indentation. Probably a self-closing tag
    return (indent * level) + xml.toxml() + "\n"
```

Finally, the last option is really similar and gets simplified to

```
    attributes = (xml.attributes or {}).items()
    node_attrs = "".join(' {}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)
    children   = "".join(node.toxml() for node in xml.childNodes)

    make_node = "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>{children}</{xml.nodeName}>\n".format

    return make_node(node_attrs=node_attrs, children=children, tab=indent * level, xml=xml)
```

Since the first and last options share quite a lot of logic, reshape the control flow to accomodate:

```
def prettyXML(xml, indent="  ", level=0):
    if not xml.childNodes:
        # Just add the raw XML with indentation. Probably a self-closing tag
        return (indent * level) + xml.toxml() + "\n"

    attributes = (xml.attributes or {}).items()
    node_attrs = "".join(' {}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)

    # Indent iff has non-text
    if has_non_text(xml):
        children = "".join(prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1) for child in xml.childNodes)

        make_node = (
            "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>\n"
            "{children}"
            "{tab}</{xml.nodeName}>\n"
        ).format

    # Only had text children
    else:
        children = "".join(node.toxml() for node in xml.childNodes)

        make_node = "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>{children}</{xml.nodeName}>\n".format

    return make_node(node_attrs=node_attrs, children=children, tab=indent * level, xml=xml)
```

The `make_node`s could do with being a fully-fledged function. This gives:

```
def is_text(node):
    return node.nodeType in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)

def has_non_text(xml):
    return not all(is_text(node) for node in xml.childNodes)

def make_node(xml, node_attrs, children, tab, *, indented):
    if indented:
        fmt = (
            "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>\n"
            "{children}"
            "{tab}</{xml.nodeName}>\n"
        )
    else:
        fmt = "{tab}<{xml.nodeName}{node_attrs}>{children}</{xml.nodeName}>\n"

    return fmt.format(xml=xml, node_attrs=node_attrs, children=children, tab=tab)

def prettyXML(xml, indent="  ", level=0):
    if not xml.childNodes:
        # Just add the raw XML with indentation. Probably a self-closing tag
        return (indent * level) + xml.toxml() + "\n"

    attributes = (xml.attributes or {}).items()
    node_attrs = "".join(' {}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in attributes)

    indented = has_non_text(xml)

    if indented:
        children = "".join(prettyXML(child, indent, level + 1) for child in xml.childNodes)
    else:
        children = "".join(node.toxml() for node in xml.childNodes)

    return make_node(xml, node_attrs, children, tab=indent*level, indented=indented)
```

Comment: As removing all the `# end` comments by hand may be annoying, you may append [this code](http://pastebin.com/Vf3FwiKX) at the end of your programme and then run to have the `# end` comments automatically stripped.

Comment: I finished reading the spec, aside from the #end comments, I don't see anything that breaks the standard. I use suggested indentation, () on if statements are shown as okay. `++` I forgot didn't work in Python: I'm used to C based languages where that does something, so thanks for pointing that out. Now to dig through the rest of your critique... :)

Comment: @Caridorc, I just used a regex replace in Notepad++.

Comment: @David You missed naming conventions (most things as `snake_case`). I'm surprised it doesn't explicitly mention `()` on `if` statements as being bad, but it definitely doesn't say they're OK either. The only uses used brackets for line continuation, which is different to what you did. Plus, you should have a space in that case anyway (`if (x or\ny)`). There's also "Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged."